# Using NumberPicker Widget with Strings

Tags: android

Is there a way to use the Android NumberPicker widget for choosing strings instead of integers?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

```
NumberPicker picker = new NumberPicker(this);
picker.setMinValue(0);
picker.setMaxValue(2);
picker.setDisplayedValues( new String[] { "Belgium", "France", "United Kingdom" } );
```

Comment: The key for me there was you have to set the displayedValues AND the min and max before it works. Thanks.

Comment: But when i click on the text, the soft keyboard pops out and I can edit the text.

Comment: @ArulxZ If you haven't already figured this out, just call picker.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS); to prevent the keyboard from popping up.

Comment: This helped me! But it appears the value 0 and I can't remove it.. Any idea? To explain in my picker appears 0, Belgium, France, United Kingdom

Comment: **FYI**: input values from keyboard can be disabled by `picker.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCE‌​NDANTS);` as @KarimVarela mentioned, however it can be very useful. It allows to input only existing values, and then finds appropriate index

Comment: I am trying various answers from few hours but nothing is showing up. I am calling the above codes under a function when clicked on a textView

Comment: NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner;                                                      
picker.setMinValue(0);                                                                                                 
 Crash in oppo android 11 version device

Answer (score 42):

```
NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
String[] arrayString= new String[]{"hakuna","matata","timon","and","pumba"};
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(arrayString.length-1);

numberPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
  @Override
  public String format(int value) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arrayString[value];
  }
});
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer.

Comment: if it is an array, then it doesn't have size() and get() methods. size() should be replaced with .length, and get() replaced with arrayString[value]

Comment: If you use formatter instead of `setDisplayedValues`, the NumberPicker won't measure its width properly, so your text might be clipped even if it can fit properly.

Answer (score 16):

```
String value = String.valueOf(picker.getValue());
```

You could mean something else, but it isn't very clear what you mean.

UPDATED:

You can fake it by setting your own formatter:

```
CountryFormatter implements Formatter {
    public String toString(int value) {
        switch(value) {
            case 0:
                return "England";
            case 1:
                return "France";
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }
}

picker.setFormatter(new CountryFormatter());
```

getValue() will still return an int, so you probably want to map the names of countries to their ids.

ADDED:
The implementation of NumberPicker has:

```
public void setRange(int start, int end, String[] displayedValues)
```

Which seems to do a better job of what you want then the above formatter.. although it isn't mentioned in the documentation so probably isn't part of the public api

Comment: I would like to use it to choose for example a country. Just like the Spinner Widget does, but without opening an additional frame at the bottom to choose a value.

Comment: Updated answer, however there are probably better ways to list countries than trying to hack NumberPicker to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I couldn't find this `setRange()` method in the docs at all! Any ideas why?

Comment: None documented methods aren't part of the public API - they aren't officially supported by google and they will probably change in the future - you use at your own risk.

Comment: In my case, this solution had a small bug, when touching one of the options, it glitched or disappeared, i dont know very well why. nan's answer didnt had this issue. Anyone can tell me what could be happening? Anyway, i think nan's answer is better and should be the accepted answer. But perhaps i'm missing something?

Comment: I had this problem: `when touching one of the options, it glitched or disappeared`. The solution was to use setDisplayedValues together with `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`. At least it loks ok now with this settings.

Comment: I found a solution for the glitch that works in APIs 18-26 without using reflection and without using `setDisplayedValues()` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949069/3918479

Answer (score 7):

try this solution, may help you

```
    NumberPicker pickers = new NumberPicker(this);
    String[] arrayPicker= new String[]{"abc","def","ghi","jkl","mno"};

    //set min value zero
    pickers.setMinValue(0);
    //set max value from length array string reduced 1
    pickers.setMaxValue(arrayPicker.length - 1);
    //implement array string to number picker
    pickers.setDisplayedValues(arrayPicker);
    //disable soft keyboard
    pickers.setDescendantFocusability(NumberPicker.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    //set wrap true or false, try it you will know the difference
    pickers.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    //create button to test selected text string
    btnPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //get position (int) from number picker
            int pos = pickers.getValue();
            //get string from number picker and position
            String selecPicker = arrayPicker[pos];  
            //test toast to get selected text string
            Toast.makeText(context, selecPicker , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
public class YourClassName extends AppCompatActivity {

NumberPicker picker = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout_file);

    picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerId_From_your_Layout_file);

     picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(3);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(new String[]{"English", "French","Kiswahili","عربى"});
}
}
```