# Android: use DatePicker control for regular numbers

Tags: android, input, datepicker, picker, android-controls

I really like the look of the DatePicker control provided by Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

But I haven't been able to find a way to use this kind of control for other entities (regular numbers, strings, etc...)  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: The `DatePicker` is based on a series of `NumberPicker` widgets. This used to be a private widget, until Honeycomb, which is why it requires API 11. You can, however, simply copy the source to your local project and it should work without problems on Gingerbread and lower too. [Displaying text in a picker is also possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings), but requires a bit of fiddling around. Finally, there are plenty of custom widgets around that offer similar functionality.