# What is a view in Android?

Tags: android, listview

[image]

I want to create a view same this one.

But I don't know what is this view?
Can you help me?

Comment: Looks like a [picker](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings) for using [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) with string values.

Comment: This looks like the Picker Widget !

Answer (score 0):

Look like[image: []]

You can see in [Wheel Picker By AigeStudio](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)

Comment: @MauDuongAu It this your answer ? :).