# How could a make a view like that with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want the `RecyclerView` to look like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: User RecyclerView  with LayoutManager, orientation as Horizontal

Comment: You can use number picker with alphabets. Reference link http://stackoverflow.com/a/25926338/2750390

also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227073/using-numberpicker-widget-with-strings

Comment: You need it like grid view right,using with recycler?

Comment: Build a custom LayoutManager like described here: https://medium.com/@v.danylo/10-steps-to-create-a-custom-layoutmanager-2f30ab2f979d

Comment: is it solved???

Comment: no couldn't solve.

Answer (score 1):

Use with GridLayoutManager for eg:

```
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 10);
holder.recycler_viewGv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

and try this link for highlighting [Highlighting center item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34586637/get-center-visible-item-of-recycleview-when-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you can try with this approach and change it as per your need

```
compile 'com.github.gastricspark:scrolldatepicker:0.0.1'
```

https://github.com/GastricSpark/ScrollDatePicker

https://github.com/hrules6872/HorizontalNumberPicker

```
<com.harrywhewell.scrolldatepicker.DayScrollDatePicker
    android:id="@+id/day_date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image]

Comment: actually i want exact the same view. ex: selected item is highlighted and rest are blur.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact what you are looking for but may give you some hint.
Use RecyclerView with horizontal layout manager.
MODIFY YOU ADAPTER CLASS
     In onBindViewHolder change your textview size based on postion

```
      if(position == mid of list){
       //Increase the text size 
      }else{
      //set the normal size to text view 
      }
```

...